# Parsing Xml with element tree in Python, same tag name

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm using python to parse a XML file but I have a problem. I'm sure there is a way to solve it but I'm new on python and parsing xml...

So here a example of xml :

```
<TeamData Ref = "1">
    <Goal></Goal>
    <Goal></Goal>
    <Goal></Goal>
    <Goal></Goal>
</TeamData>
<TeamData Ref = "2">
    <Goal></Goal>
    <Goal></Goal>
    <Goal></Goal>
    <Goal></Goal>
</TeamData>
```

I want to store my element goal in two part in function of the team ref... How would I do that ? Because I tried :

```
for iterators in child.iter("TeamData"):
                something_to_store(iterators.tag)
```

But I have the list of all the 8 goals without difference in function of the teamdata ref !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>

<TeamData Ref = "1">
    <Goal>a</Goal>
    <Goal>b</Goal>
    <Goal>c</Goal>
    <Goal>d</Goal>
</TeamData>

<TeamData Ref = "2">
    <Goal>e</Goal>
    <Goal>f</Goal>
    <Goal>g</Goal>
    <Goal>h</Goal>
</TeamData>
    </data>
```

---

for each teamdata you need to iterate again to get Goals. so create dictonary with ref name as key and goals as values

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('a.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print root
dic={}
for i in root.iter('TeamData'):
    dic[i.attrib['Ref']]=[j.text for j in i]
print dic
#output {'1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], '2': ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']}
```

Comment: what if there is a subelement between <Goal>e</Goal> and <Goal>f</Goal>? This parser seems to cannot extract text in a subelement. Please, how to also extract text from a subelement.